# Setting QGIS simple line color depending on fields value in python plugin in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am new to QGIS and using QGIS 3.6. I am trying to add a geojson file to QGIS and then export it to a png.

I have a color filed in geojson, and can apply it with GUI.
Now I want to do it using python plugin.
In the GUI, I can easily go to symbology and choose simple line, set fields as color. 
[image]

I tried some code in plugin

```
layer = iface.addVectorLayer("/Users/usr/Downloads/test8.json", "my layer", "ogr")
layer = iface.activeLayer()
single_symbol_renderer = layer.renderer()

symbol = single_symbol_renderer.symbol()
symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(0, 225, 0))
symbol.setWidth(0.75)

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

The code above can change the color to green. But I could not find any way to set the color using the color field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a data-defined property. Unfortunately, the only such property you can set at the symbol level is the width. So, to set a data defined color, you must use the [`setDataDefinedProperty`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsSymbolLayer.html#a983d2ff80387738ce710f80d55a8503b) method of the `QgsSymbolLayer`

In your case, you have only one symbol layer, so get it using `symbol.symbolLayers()[0]`

```
layer = iface.addVectorLayer("/Users/usr/Downloads/test8.json", "my layer", "ogr")
layer = iface.activeLayer()
single_symbol_renderer = layer.renderer()

symbol = single_symbol_renderer.symbol()
symbol_layer = symbol.symbolLayers()[0]
data_defined = QgsProperty.fromField("color")  # "color" is the name of the field
symbol_layer.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyStrokeColor, data_defined)
symbol.setWidth(0.75)

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like magic. It save my day!

Comment: By the way: If you want to remove the `data defined properties`, you might want to use `symbol_layer.dataDefinedProperties().clear()`